# Interchromosomic vs Intrachromosomic Recombinations

Tags: genetics

What is the difference between interchromosomic and intrachromosomic recombinations?

I did a research about them and saw some videos (e.g. [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4UaJkJtlYs) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BlnUNmfGn7I)) with animations on YouTube. But I'm still lost between them and can't differentiate between these two expressions.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. It always help to show what you found. Linking to the youtube videos you've watched would be could.

Comment: The link should be added in the question (using the 'edit' button) not in a comment and especially not as an answer. I edited your post to add the link. You can now delete your comment and your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefix *inter-* means "between two or more", and the prefix *intra-* means "within one".

So *inter*chromosomal recombination means recombination between two different chromosomes (for example, it normally and often occurs between each homologous paternal and maternal chromosome pair during the Prophase I stage of meiosis).

*Intra*chromosomal recombination would mean recombination within a single chromosome.

Comment: Thnx alot beautiful explanation